# Image in PageViewer not stretching accordingly

Tags: android, layout, pageviews

I have 2 PageViewers with 2 series of pictures each. Initially they were one close to another, but then I decided to make them overlap. To do that, I increased one's height with, let's say, y. 
I want the overlapping to be visible only for the images with bigger height(they're PNGs), so the ones with the initial ViewPager height would look just like before the resizing
[image]

[image]

So, once I applied the y height, I saw that a gap appeared in the resized pageviewer, making the image decalate with y px. This somewhat seems normal, but ruins the mechanism, because I want the starting point of any image to be the upper-left corner of the pageviewer. I tried and researched all the layout attributes & pageviewer methods for something to help me set the starting point but I kinda went out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

android:layout_alignParentTop="true" to make the image to be the upper-left corner of the pageviewer.

For imageView we can set this property:

android:scaleType="fitXY"